# How to transform this NSImage code for use on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, macos, uiimageview, nsimage

I am attempting at turning some code written for Mac OS X into an iOS application. This is the working code for OS X:

```
// To create the images on the view:
NSRect imageRect = NSMakeRect(24+(i*80), ypos, 72, 96);
    NSImageView *theImageView=[[NSImageView alloc] initWithFrame:imageRect];
    [theImageView setBounds:imageRect];
    [self addSubview:theImageView];
    [theImageView setImage:[tCard image]];
    [self.imageviews addObject:theImageView];

// To remove the images on the view:
    for (NSImageView *timageview in self.imageviews) {
    [timageview removeFromSuperview];
}
[self.imageviews removeAllObjects];
```

At the moment, I have:

```
//To create the image on the view
UIImageView * theImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(24+(i*80), ypos, 72, 96)];
    [self addSubview:theImageView];
    [theImageView setImage:[tCard image]];
    [self.imageviews addObject:theImageView];

// To remove the images on the view:
 for (UIImageView *timageview in self.imageviews) {
    [timageview removeFromSuperview];
}
[self.imageviews removeAllObjects];
```

However! The removing of images does *not* work. The images are shown fine on the view, but I cannot remove them. To be totally honest, I'm not 100% sure about how the sample code completely works, but I am hacking away and trying to work it out, hence why I seem to be sort of half way there, but can't get the images to remove :'(

I appreciate your following input! Any questions or more information required let me know.

**EDIT:** This is how `self.imageviews` is initialized:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
    self.imageviews = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:4]; 
}
return self;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Just as a guess, I think the key is `self.imageviews`. I'm guessing that you're not initializing it. Somewhere you should have something like `self.imageviews = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Tried it, but to no avail, unfortunately!

Comment: @BenToscano could you post the code for how self.imageviews get initialized?